# Make Border Resizable

Tags: css

I am using the border below and want to print various texts. I'd like it to be resizable, to end where the given first name ends. For example, to end after '-' here. If "Peter" is given by user, to end after "r" etc. I've searched and found about % width but that's standard and doesn't depend on text given. Any ideas? Thanks a lot

I use:

```
p.firstb {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying your `p` as an `inline-block` should be enough.

Comment: Either this, or use an inline element such as `span` or `b`.